# Python Requests Post - HTTPSConnectionPool Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Hi I have a simple code hosted on my Flask server to POST to my API

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

try:
            url = "apiv2.xxxxxxxx.com/testpost"
            session = requests.Session()
            retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
            adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
            session.mount('http://', adapter)
            session.mount('https://', adapter)
            
            response = session.post(url)
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
```

However, it caught an exception and the error message is as follows:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apiv2.drobaio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /authuser/$2b$10$wLkkKBi9g/gAAAAABgqr74HzvCs09eVY4O4YvkvXlf6lNe0uk9QG3Qp4g0lKzmgVFwLdQ50K1hptKKyguR2RrZJNJJnOlUs0LnyaqgefZ04g==/gAAAAABgqr74tJyvGCcFEpw3fdcKALlZUv-RHi3u0hdJJtgUDCE0Ga3hqoilUPL6vu3iTDzt2NDfX8UgfrcgQQFr3IFnfSDq_g== (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? I don't think there's an issue with my code as I tried executing this on my own PC and it works.

Comment: It seems to be a DNS resolution issue. Plus, if you visit http://apiv2.drobaio.com/ there is an error, which suggests that the problem is on their end.

Comment: @Anonymous Hi! That Error that shows when visiting that site is planned. I coded it to show that Error. A little update, i tried to curl that url and it says `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: apiv2.drobaio.com; Name or service not known`